# convert text to emoticons using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to convert text to emoticons. It coverts text of a div of class "content" to emoticons. It works fine, but, the content is also updated via ajax. Those 'content' divs don't get the converted emoticons. How to get it right?

```
jQuery.fn.emoticons = function(icon_folder) {
          var icon_folder = icon_folder || "/site-media/static/images/emoticons";
          var emotes = {"smile": Array(":-)",":)","=]","=)"),
              "sad": Array(":-(","=(",":[",":&lt;"),
              "wink": Array(";-)",";)",";]","*)"),
              "grin": Array(":D","=D","XD","BD","8D","xD"),
              "surprise": Array(":O","=O",":-O","=-O"),
              "devilish": Array("(6)"),
              "angel": Array("(A)"),
              "crying": Array(":'(",":'-("),
              "plain": Array(":|"),
          "smile-big": Array(":o)"),
          "glasses": Array("8)","8-)"),
          "kiss": Array("(K)",":-*"),
          "monkey": Array("(M)")};

      function emoticons(html){
        for(var emoticon in emotes){
          for(var i = 0; i < emotes[emoticon].length; i++){
        /* css class of images is emoticonimg for styling them*/
          html = html.replace(emotes[emoticon][i],"<img src=\""+icon_folder+"/face-"+emoticon+".png\" class=\"emoticonimg\" height=\"20\" width=\"20\" alt=\""+emotes[emoticon][i]+"\"/>","g");
          }
        }
        return html;
      }
      return this.each(function(){
        $(this).html(emoticons($(this).html()));
      });
    };

    $('.content').emoticons();
```